# How to pass values from child shell to parent shell

Tags: shell

How to pass values from child shell to parent shell in shell programming?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is impossible. The best that can be done is for the child to print the desired assignments, and for the parent to `exec` them.

Comment: can't we do that using global variables?

Comment: @Sunil There might be a way to avoid the child shell. Try if you can make some changes in the shell functions.

Answer (score 3):

See my answers [here](https://superuser.com/questions/144020/environment-variable-issue-in-shell/144049#144049) and [here](https://superuser.com/questions/143413/linux-environment-variables/143418#143418) for discussions and demonstrations of variable scoping in the shell. There aren't any global variables.

The usual methods for passing values include printing the value or using a temporary file.

Example child and parent:

```
#!/bin/sh
# child.sh
a=4321
echo $a
```

and

```
#!/bin/sh
# parent.sh
val=$(child.sh)
echo $val
```

Answer (score -1):

If you want to return an integer use the exit status to do the same.

```
exit x # x can be any integer
```

Comment: Eep! This is not a good practice imo. Exit status codes are to be used for indicating whether or not a process has failed, and any other use breaks the principle of least surprise for any future dev

Comment: Jees. I can't believe I wrote that answer 8 years back. @Nick, It is not at all a good practice :)